# doxygen preprocessing C file

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, doxygen

I have the following **C** code, I want to preprocess with doxygen and generate a call graph (I set ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = TRUE):

```
#define CALL_ENABLE 1
#define REPORT_ERROR_TEST 0

#if (CALL_ENABLE == 1)
void FuncLogError()
{
   #if (REPORT_ERROR_TEST == 1)
   FuncReportStatus();
   #endif
}
#endif
```

In the call graph I obtain `FuncLogError` calls `FuncReportStatus`, despite the const `REPORT_ERROR_TEST` is equal 0.It seems like preprocessing is ignored for condition  `#if (REPORT_ERROR_TEST == 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell doxygen about the macro values? If not, use

```
PREDEFINED=CALL_ENABLE=1
PREDEFINED+=REPORT_ERROR_TEST=0
MACRO_EXPANSION=YES
```

in the doxygen configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you could disable the pre-processing done by doxygen:

```
# If the ENABLE_PREPROCESSING tag is set to YES, doxygen will evaluate all
# C-preprocessor directives found in the sources and include files.
# The default value is: YES.

ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
```